# Adding new method to interface

Tags: java

I am using an interface in my code which has been there for a long time and many classes have implemented it.
Now i have to add a new method to this interface for a new class [old classes dont need the new method]. So as has been suggested at many places that i can extend that old interface and create a new one with new method.
Now my problem is that app launcher which uses the interface implementation is only having reference to base interface and using base interface i can't call method in new interface.

```
baseInterface is extended by newInterface

Class Applauncher{

  baseInterface b;

}
```

So as can be seen i can't call new method in "newInterface" in Applauncher class.

I want a solution which will not shake up my old implementation.

Comment: Why do you need to add this method in your interface if there is only one class using it?

Comment: At present just one and it has to implement baseInterface + new method.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing - are you saying that your `Applauncher` class cannot be changed, and holds a reference to `baseInterface` - but the actual reference being stored is to a `newInterface`?  If so, I think you might be able to handle your problem with casting.  So `newInterface asNew = (newInterface) b`, where `b` is a variable of type `baseInterface` which actually stores a reference to `newInterface`.

Comment: Why don't you simply add the method you need to the new class without adding it to the interface?

Comment: Yes Applaunch class is not supposed to be changed. I need to amke a call "newInterface.newMethod()" in AppLauncher but with current implementation i can't do that. You are doing down casting i.e base class to child class, java should throw exception, isn't it?

Comment: Supposed you have your `BaseInterface` with a `methodA();` and your `NewInterface extends BaseInterface` with a `methodB();` : this is the method that you want to be used by only one class, let's say `NewClass`. If there is and will always be only one class that needs this `methodB();`, then just implement it into your class. If you think that for the moment only `NewClass` needs `methodB();` but there will be other classes in the future that will need it too, then just create `NewClass implements NewInterface` and it will implement `methodA();` and `methodB()`.

Comment: @assylias: That will be a crude solution which wont be extensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically at the point where you need to call the new methods in your applauncher, you could do something like this:

```
if (b instanceof NewInterface) {
  ((NewInterface)b).newMethod();
}
```

Would that be a solution for you?

Comment: I agree, i would look for a more neat solution but if i dont get any other way then your approach will suit me most.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a solution you want to use too much, but in cases like yours it makes sense...

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly not yet released, but when Java 8 comes out you'll have a nice solution to this general issue:

```
public interface MyInterface {
   Calendar myMethod();
   Object myMeth2() default null;
}
```

The important point there is the `default null` bit - the default keyword has a new usage from 8 onwards which allows you to specify default return values (meaning you don't need to implement this method in all implementations.)

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 on wards provides a facility to create default methods inside the interface. Methods which are defined inside the interface and tagged with default are known as default methods. These methods are non-abstract methods. They allow adding new methods to interfaces without breaking the interface for those that already implement it.

```
interface MyInterface {    
    // default method    
    default void method1(){    
        System.out.println("Hello, this is default method");    
    }    
    // Already existing Abstract method    
    void method2(String msg); 
}
```